# Is it possible to use custom truststore with SOAPConnection?

Tags: java, ssl, soap, certificate, truststore

(This is with Java 7.)

We are considering using `javax.xml.soap.SOAPConnection` and its associated stuff to do some relatively quick and dirty sending and receiving of SOAP messages.

However, the server this will be connecting uses certificates whose trust anchors are **not** in the default Java 7 truststore.  We do not want to modify the default truststore but instead want to use a custom truststore.

If we were working at a lower level we could do stuff like getting an `SSLContext`, reinitializing it with the custom truststore, getting an `SSLSocketFactory` from it and so on.

But from what I can see in the `SOAPConnection` API and the APIs of associated classes there is no obvious way to change the `SSLContext` instance that `SOAPConnection` implementations use.  I could change the default context but that changes things JVM-wide which is not what we want to have happen.

Are we just out of luck if we want to use `SOAPConnection` then?  Any other libraries that will let you create SOAP requests relatively simply but let you specify the `SSLContext` or `SSLSocketFactory` to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Additional research shows pretty clearly that there is no way to do this within the SOAP classes -- they always use the JVM-wide defaults.

So I ended up using the approach in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24561444/411393) where you make a custom trustmanager that is a composite of two trustmanagers -- one built from the default truststore and one built from the custom truststore -- and then inject that composite trustmanager into the default `SSLContext`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. When running the java application pass trust-store/key-store details as following. Append following to your normal execution code.

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=myKS.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=123456  -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=myTS.jks   -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=123456
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't really help the specific problem.  As I said in my question "...but that changes things JVM-wide which is not what we want to have happen".  Your proposed solution would change the truststore for the entire JVM.