# How can I call an api endpoint using a public certificate using lambda function java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, lambda, cacerts

I Have a aws lambda function built in java.

When i try to call one api endpoint i get this error:

"PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target".

I tried to import the public certificate CRT but not worked:

```
 - echo "Install My certificates"
      - aws s3 cp s3://myrepositoria/mycacert.crt 
      - cp mycacert.crt  /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/mycacert.crt
      - ls /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
      - keytool -import -noprompt -trustcacerts -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts -alias mycacert -file /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/mycacert.crt -storepass changeit
      - update-ca-certificates
      - apt-get install jq
```

But I get error when I call an api endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple errors in your command.  First is that you can only write to `/tmp` in an AWS Lambda by default.  So start with:

```
- echo "Install My certificates"
  - aws s3 cp s3://myrepositoria/mycacert.crt /tmp/mycacert.crt
```

Then, following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47175713/import-external-cert-in-aws), you'll need to change your code to use the certificate store in `/tmp` instead of the default.  Note that a quick check to see if your custom store is there could be an optimization in case of a warm Lambda start.

Lastly, you're not on Ubuntu/Debian.  `apt-get` will not work.  To install `jq`, instead run `yum install jq`