# System.setProperty not working on second call

Tags: java, ssl, jsse

I am using `System.setProperty()` to set `javax.ssl.truststore` and `keystore` values at runtime. But when I set it again with different values inside the code, the changes are not reflected. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand the down votes on the question. It is a legitimate one, but on the other side you could provide some code. Help us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

As you're not giving any code, not easy to answer. What I only can guess is that you forgot to initialize correctly the SSL context after updating the properties. Have a look at [SSLContext.init()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLContext.html#init(javax.net.ssl.KeyManager[],%20javax.net.ssl.TrustManager[],%20java.security.SecureRandom)) . This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24555890/using-a-custom-truststore-in-java-as-well-as-the-default-one) may help too.

Answer (score 0):

This system property is used in a cached instance. If you want different ssl settings, please use a SSLContext.