# Solving "unable to find valid certification path" without turning off security or manually appending cacerts

Tags: java, security, ssl, ssl-certificate, truststore

I'm getting an exception when trying to connect to a site:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: 
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: 
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: 
    unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I've read that I would need to add the public key of the site to the `cacerts` file. Or I've seen solutions where they completely turn off this security feature.

Is it possible to add that one public key to the trusted keys from code?

**edit:** I would like to connect to this site from this application only, there is no need to add it globally for other Java programs. This would be a client application that should not really modify the host environment.

Comment: You implement your own custom TrustManager, then use that to initialize an SSLContext, then you can retrieve an SSLSocketFactory from this SSLContext that will use your TrustManager. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24555890/238704) and answer for most of the details, though you'll need to adapt it for your needs.